# how to wait for variable update for new calculation in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await

Hey I'm trying to build dashboard for calculate my medicine supplier total outstanding using nextjs.

*below *is my **createPurchase **api.

`

```
import PurchaseOrder from '../../models/PurchaseOrder'
import Supplier from '../../models/Supplier'
import connectDB from '../../middleware/mongoose';
import Medicine from '../../models/Medicine';

const handler = async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {

        const medicines = [];
        let totalOrderAmount = 0;
        let totalPaybleGst = 0;

        req.body.medicines.forEach(async medicine => {

            let medicineOne = await Medicine.findById(medicine.medicine)
            let newQuantity = parseInt(medicineOne.quantity) + parseInt(medicine.quantity)
            const filter = { _id: medicine.medicine };
            const update = { quantity: newQuantity };

            await Medicine.findByIdAndUpdate(filter, update);

            let newmedi = {
                name: medicine.name,
                company: medicine.company,
                medicine: medicineOne,
                quantity: newQuantity,
                pack_detail: medicine.pack_detail,
                category: medicine.category,
                batch: medicine.batch,
                mrp: medicine.mrp,
                rate: medicine.rate,
                gst: medicine.gst,
                totalAmount: medicine.totalAmount,
                expiryDate: medicine.expiryDate
            }

            totalOrderAmount += medicine.totalAmount;
            totalPaybleGst += medicine.gst * medicine.rate * medicine.quantity * 0.01;
            medicines.push(newmedi);
        })

        const paidAmount = req.body.paidAmount

        const supplierBeforeUpdate = await Supplier.findById(req.body.supplier);
        const newOustanding = supplierBeforeUpdate.totalOutstanding + totalPaybleGst + totalOrderAmount - paidAmount;

        const filter = { _id: req.body.supplier };
        const update = { totalOutstanding: newOustanding };

        await Supplier.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
        const supplierAffterUpdate = await Supplier.findById(req.body.supplier);

        const purchaseOrder = await PurchaseOrder.create({
            supplier: supplierAffterUpdate,
            createdBy: req.body.createdBy,
            medicines: medicines,
            paybleGst: totalPaybleGst,
            totalAmount: totalOrderAmount,
            grandTotal: totalPaybleGst + totalOrderAmount,
            paidAmount: paidAmount
        })
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, purchaseOrder: purchaseOrder })
    }
    else {
        res.status(400).json({ error: "This method is not allowed" })
    }
}

export default connectDB(handler);
```

`

this is my **purchaseOrder Schema**

`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema, model, models } = mongoose;

const medicinePurchaseSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    company: { type: String, required: true },
    medicine: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Medicine'
    },
    quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    pack_detail: { type: String, required: true },
    batch: { type: String, required: true },
    mrp: { type: Number, required: true },
    rate: { type: Number, required: true },
    gst: { type: Number, required: true },
    totalAmount: { type: Number, required: true },
    expiryDate: { type: Date, required: true }
});

const purchaseOrderSchema = new Schema({
    supplier: { type: Object, required: true},
    createdBy: { type: String, required: true },
    medicines: [medicinePurchaseSchema],
    paybleGst: { type: Number, required: true },
    totalAmount: { type: Number, required: true },
    paidAmount: { type: Number, required: true },
    grandTotal: { type: Number, required: true }
}, { timestamps: true })

const PurchaseOrder = models.PurchaseOrder || model('PurchaseOrder', purchaseOrderSchema);

export default PurchaseOrder;
```

`

`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema, model, models } = mongoose;

const medicineSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    company: {type: String, required: true},
    pack_detail: {type: Number, required: true},
    quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    category: { type: String, required: true },
    status: { type: String, required: true }
}, { timestamps: true });

const Medicine = models.Medicine || model('Medicine', medicineSchema);

export default Medicine;
```

`
this is my **Medicine schema**

but problem is I got **totalOrderAmount **and **totalPayableGst **is **0 **in newOutstanding calculation, i think my *newOutstanding calculation line is executing before updating my these variable* in medicines.each function.

How can I fix this, im trying since 2 days but i didn't get any solution.

anyone have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

That `forEach` method call will execute synchronously and doesn't await any promises. The callbacks do have `await`, but those affect only the `async` function they occur in, not the `forEach` method.

Instead of using `forEach`, use `map`, so that you get back the array of promises (as the `async` callbacks return promises). To make sure those promises resolve to something useful, have those callbacks return the `newmedi`. With `Promise.all` you can then know when all those promises resolved, and get all the medicine values to store in the `medicines` array, and only continue with the rest of the function when that is done:

```
// Not forEach, but map, and await all returned promises
const medicines = await Promise.all(req.body.medicines.map(async medicine => {
    /* ...rest of your callback code... */
    return newmedi; // Don't push, but return it
}));
```